# In C#.NET, how to add version number to static file references, such as HTML and CSS?

Tags: c#, .net, html

So I'm building a web app using C#.NET, and would like to add a version number to file references. For example:

```
<script src="mysite/scripts/default.123.js"></script>
```

Each time I modify files in the web app, including cshtml, CSS, JS, or images, is it possible to have that version number incremented dynamically? **In other words, how do I get [or create] the version number in the first place? Is it possible?**

This is to avoid caching old copies on the client browsers, especially when being served via XHR. For reasons I don't want to take the time to explain, I am NOT asking for alternative methods, such as dummmy parameters, no-cache meta tags, datetimestamps, CDN's etc.

I'd like this number to correspond to the most recent version of file that was modified - maybe "build version" isn't the right word. As Kyle Trauberman, assemblyversion might might work. However will this accomodate for changes to static resources, such as HTML or CSS? What is a good method for that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To solve this problem, I go with a slightly different approach.  Rather than using a "version number", I simply append the last modified date.  To make things convenient, I wrote a helper method:

```
public static HtmlString Script<T>(this HtmlHelper<T> html, string path)
{
    var file = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(path);
    DateTime lastModified = File.GetLastWriteTime(file);

    TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("script");
    builder.Attributes["src"] = path + "?modified=" + lastModified.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
    return new HtmlString(builder.ToString());
}
```

Then in your views (not sure if you're using MVC, but the solution is similar in either case), you can use:

```
@Html.Script("/Scripts/common.js")
```

Which will output:

```
<script src="/Scripts/common.js?modified=20120129025804"></script>
```

**Note:**  Page Speed is not happy with the use of the query string.  However, I tried changing it to using a "/" and that resulted in MVC taking over the routing for the file, and preventing IIS from handling it.  Not sure how to resolve that.

Comment: Looks promising, however I'd like to place the # thusly: common.123.js . I guess it's just a string builder so should be easy enough to do.

Comment: @Josh The downside to placing the version in the file name instead of in a query string is that when an update is made, you need to update all references of that file to the new file name, which can be time consuming and tedious.  With the query string, you don't need to do this.

Comment: @Josh I suppose you could define a custom route if you're dead-set on placing the version number in the file name.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman Good point, but if all the references are implemented as above, they would be completely dynamic as well :)

Comment: @Josh Kirk's solution of using the file last modified date would work for updates to only the static file and not the whole project.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman that's what I'm looking for :) I can modify the code a bit to add a ".###" before the trailing ".xyz", and it should work for any ol' static resource

Answer (score 1):

To avoid caching of old versions of a file, you can append a query string to the url:

```
<script src="mysite/scripts/default.js?v=123" />
```

The value you pass to the query string is irrelevent, as you'll most likely be ignoring it server side.  This prevents the browser from caching the file.  **You can place the assemblyversion of your project in the query string, to allow caching of the file unless you update the project.**

Comment: @Josh Why the downvote?  I answered the question you highlighted in your question.  See the bold text in my answer.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because the first thing I saw was you telling me to do something other than I was asking. In fact I specifically stated I DO NOT WANT ALTERNATIVE METHODS. In re-reading the bold portion on your answer, assemblyversion might be what I was looking for. Does that include changes that are made to CSS or JS resource files? (not just the compiled app)

Comment: It would only include changes to your compiled app, but if you're using an auto-incrementing version (ex. 1.0.*) in your AssemblyInfo.cs, then that value would reflect changes when you rebuild and deploy.

Comment: Also, What you you mean by "alternative methods"? That's very vague.

Comment: Arrrrggghh! I'm ANGRY! LOL - Sorry... too much coffee today :) Agreed on the vagueness. Updating my question as we speak.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making the version as part of the file name, you can put it as a query string at the end, i.e.:

```
<script src="mysite/scripts/defualt.js?v=123" > </script>
```

I believe most modern browsers respect this, but I don't know if it would be 100% effective on all browsers.

Also, as a quick aside, I realize your example is probably that, just an example, but you shouldn't use a self-closing external script tag, it causes issues with most browsers.

Comment: PLEASE READ MY POST.  How do I get the version number in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the note on the self-closing script BTW. I was only an example - geez, you stackoverflow guys don't let ANYTHING get by, do you? :)